# Using Lock to stop concurrent executions is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, concurrency, locking

I have an API in which i do a lot of processing like sending a service bus queue message and receiving it, adding entries to table and then finally send an event to socket.io server. I want all this to be protected by concurrent executions. I am using Lock, but it doesnt seem to do the trick. Am i missing anything? below is my code

```
 public class BroadcastController : ApiController
{
private readonly Object _Lock = new Object();

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("UploadRecording")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadRecording()
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string path = Path.GetTempPath();            

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(path);                       

        // Read the form data and return an async task.
        var response = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

// processing the mime content

lock (_Lock)
            {

                // sending and receiving service bus messages
                // adding records to table
               // sending an event to socket.io

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ResponseMessage<PersistedAudioRecord> { SuccessCode = 1, Message = "Broadcast Uploaded", Data = updatedRecord });
}   }    }
```

Comment: Are you making multiple `UploadRecording` calls on the _same instance_ of `BroadcastController`? Or are you making multiple instances of this class? The lock as you have it now will only be used _per instance_ and not shared across multiple instances. (if you do have multiple instances, just redefine `_Lock` as `static`)

Comment: Damnn!! silly me!! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the _Lock object static. Otherwise, you are using a different lock for each instance of the controller. Since the framework creates a new instance of the controller to process each request, each request is locking on a different _Lock object, thus providing no concurrency safety.

However, note that even a static lock object will only work if you have a single server. If you have multiple servers handling requests you'll need to manage concurrency by another means.